# React-Native custom TextInput placeholderTextColor, how to apply on custom style?

Tags: react-native

I created and used custom TextInput for my project,

```
import { TextInput as OldTextInput } from "react-native";

function TextInput(props) {
  const { style, ...otherProps } = props;
  const defaultStyle = {
    fontFamily: "poppins",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#ffffffac",
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#194F4D",
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    width: "100%",
    color: "white",
  };
  const mergedStyle = { ...defaultStyle, ...style };

  return <OldTextInput style={mergedStyle} {...otherProps} />;
}

export default TextInput;
```

I am using it inside of the components like this:

```
  <TextInput
      placeholder="placeholder"
      placeholderTextColor="#ffffffac"
      cursorColor="#ffffffac"
      onFocus={() => handleInputFocus()}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      value={reminderName}
      onChangeText={(text) => setReminderName(text)}
   ></TextInput>
```

I want to put "placeholderTextColor and cursorColor" into my custom TextInput component and could not achieve it.

I searched online and checked documents and github issues etc. could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *placeholderTextColor* is the property of the TextInput component, and not part of style, you can directly place it inside your custom OldTextInput component like this:

```
<OldTextInput {...otherProps}
    style={mergedStyle} 
    placeholderTextColor="#ffffffac" 
    cursorColor="#ffffffac" 
/>
```